# print_r() displays sql statement instead of printing the pdo result set?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to debug why the below query does not return a result set.  When I tried debugging this using print_r to see what this sql returns , i get the sql statement itself instead of the result set.  Can someone help me with why this doesn't return a result set ?

Edit: I am using query function of the PHP Data Objects

```
  $query = "select * from categories order by categoryID";

  $categories = $db->query($query);

  print_r($categories);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that method returns a `PDOStatement` object, as stated [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), not an associative array. You have to get the resultset from this object first.

You could use [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get all the results in an associative array (or any other PDO fetch method according to your taste):

```
print_r($categories->fetchAll());
```

When you encounter problems like this, it is always advisable to read the manual.

Comment: Thanks that does print the array..., however i was using a foreach loop in the code that followed to populate a select and that did work ...so wasn't sure why the print_r did not work...

Comment: @user481913 The PDOStatement has a so-called Iterator, so when you use it in the foreach, it will always return the next result of the simple `fetch()` method. You can see the foreach example in the manual as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * from categories order by categoryID";

$query = $db->query($sql);

$categories = $query->fetchAll();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($categories);
echo "</pre>";
```